# How can I restrict user from not to select more than three checkbox in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created some code for select the code as checked or unchecked but How can we set the restriction to not select more than three.
[click](https://codeshare.io/advNKg) here to check out the code

Comment: Hold the isChecked state in an array and make sure that it doesn't exceed a length of 3 by slicing it.

Comment: There are many ways you can handle it...put max val of 3 and do operation inside of (max < checkedItems) and increment max... or put status:false field inside array and handle from that status of array.

Comment: @Patrick, not getting.. Something like this selectcheck: ["", "", "", ""]?

Comment: You have an array in your state and push the selected item, when handleSelect is fired. In handleSelect before setting the new state, you slice said array to the length of the last 3 items and then set it as your new state.

Comment: Hey @Kwall, if the answer helped you out can you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something I made very quickly just to show a working example (can be much better and shorter but I thought this will help make it more understandable). If you need any extra help, will be happy to update my answer ;)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const initialCheckBoxesState = [
  { name: "one", checked: false },
  { name: "two", checked: false },
  { name: "three", checked: false },
  { name: "four", checked: false },
  { name: "five", checked: false }
];

export default function App() {
  const [checkBoxes, setCheckedBoxes] = useState(initialCheckBoxesState);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleCheckOnClick = (event) => {
    setError("");
    let checkBoxIndex = checkBoxes.findIndex(
      (box) => box.name === event.target.name
    );
    let copyOfCheckBoxes = [...checkBoxes];
    let isChecked = copyOfCheckBoxes[checkBoxIndex].checked;
    let amountOfCheckedBoxes = checkBoxes.filter((box) => box.checked);

    if (!isChecked && amountOfCheckedBoxes.length > 2) {
      setError("Max of 3 checked checkboxes");
      return;
    }

    if (isChecked) {
      copyOfCheckBoxes[checkBoxIndex] = {
        ...copyOfCheckBoxes[checkBoxIndex],
        checked: false
      };
    } else {
      copyOfCheckBoxes[checkBoxIndex] = {
        ...copyOfCheckBoxes[checkBoxIndex],
        checked: true
      };
    }

    setCheckedBoxes(copyOfCheckBoxes);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {checkBoxes.map((box, index) => {
        return (
          <input
            key={index}
            type="checkbox"
            name={box.name}
            onChange={handleCheckOnClick}
            checked={box.checked}
          />
        );
      })}
      <span>{error}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```